# Screens turning off unecessarily

Tags: windows-10, display, multiple-monitors, power-management, external-display

I just started at a new job.

I've been given two big samsung monitors. (I'm not sure what exact model. Device manager doesn't report anything)

When I lock the screen, the lock screen picture displays for like two minutes but then the screens blank out and display this ugly "no signal" message.

I have set all the windows 10 power options (that I am aware of) such that the screen should stay on. Why is it doing this?

Cheers

Comment: Often this is something your System administrator sets in the Group policies to save energy. This is normal and expected.

Comment: Pretty much every other desk in the office has monitors that don't do this. Also, the monitors don't actually "turn off" to "save energy", they just display this massive uglyass error message.

Comment: This is expected behavior. When locked, Windows will put the display to sleep after *1* minute. It’s great for saving power, too. If your displays don’t go to sleep properly, that’s on them

Comment: @TheIronKnuckle They don't display the 'No Signal' message or they don't turn off?

Comment: None of the screens in the office turn off. However every other screen has an attractive picture displayed whereas mine just displays a crappy "no signal" message. aesthetics are important. A beautiful workstation is a productive workstation. I wanna get this sorted

Comment: @DanielB you clearly haven't read the question or any of the comments

Comment: just to be sure, you tried 'Win + X' -> 'Power Options' -> 'Monitor' -> 'Turn off after:' -> 'never' ?

Comment: @NordlysJeger yes.

Comment: @TheIronKnuckle are there any energy settings you can change in the monitor OSD?

Comment: @TheIronKnuckle I thought you wanted help. Guess I was wrong. Again: There is a special display sleep timer on the lock screen. What you do with this information is now up to you.

Comment: @DanielB I obviously want help, and none of your comments are contributing in any productive way

Answer (score 0):

I discovered a setting in the "Lock screen settings" page. I set all of the screen timeouts to "never" and now my lock screen stays on and beautiful as it should